# STI and polymorphs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, single-table-inheritance

I have problem with my code

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class NewsArticle < Post
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy, :order => 'created_at'
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true, :counter_cache => true
end
```

And on attempt go get comments for some NewsArticle i see in logs something like

```
  Comment Load (0.9ms)   SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."commentable_id" = 1 and "comments"."commentable_type" = 'Post') ORDER BY created_at
```

Strange that **"commentable_type" = 'Post'**.
What's wrong?

PS: Rails 2.3.5 && ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i686-darwin10]

Answer (score 5):

The **commentable_type** field needs to store the name of the table that contains the data, once that row is loaded from the right table, the inherited type will be loaded from the **type** column on the **Posts** table.

So:

Here the comment points to the table that it comments on.  The posts table, id 1

```
>> Comment.first
=> #<Comment id: 1, commentable_id: 1, commentable_type: "Post", body: "test", created_at: "2010-04-09 00:56:36", updated_at: "2010-04-09 00:56:36">
```

Then to load the NewsArticle, id 1 is loaded from posts, and the type there indicates a NewsArticle.

```
>> Comment.first.commentable
=> #<NewsArticle id: 1, type: "NewsArticle", name: "one", body: "body", created_at: "2010-04-09 00:55:35", updated_at: "2010-04-09 00:55:35">
>> Comment.first.commentable.class.table_name
=> "posts"
```

If **commentable_type** held `"NewsArticle"` it would have to look at the class to determine the table.  This way it can just look to the table and worry about the type once it gets there.

Comment: For the polymorphic relationship, only the table matters, once that table is loaded, the inheritance type can be determined.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Polymorphic Associations section of [ActiveRecord::Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) API.  There is a little bit about using polymorphic associations in combination with single table inheritance.  Following the second code example in that section I think this might be close to what you want

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true, :counter_cache => true

  def commentable_type=(sType)
   super(sType.to_s.classify.constantize.base_class.to_s)
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy, :order => 'created_at'
end

class NewsArticle < Post
end
```

Answer (score 1):

def commentable_type=(sType)
   super(sType.to_s.classify.constantize.base_class.to_s)
  end

This method is returning class as Post, what to do if you want to store the inherited class Post as commentable_type?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I had exactly the same problem using Rails 3.1. Looks the problem is not solved yet. Apparently, using polymorphic associations in combination with Single Table Inheritance (STI) in Rails is a bit complicated.

The current Rails documentation for Rails 3.2 gives this advice for combining [polymorphic associations and STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Polymorphic+Associations):

> Using polymorphic associations in combination with single table
>   inheritance (STI) is a little tricky. In order for the associations to
>   work as expected, ensure that you store the base model for the STI
>   models in the type column of the polymorphic association.

In your case the base model would be "Post", i.e. "commentable_type" should be "Post" for all comments.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there's actually nothing wrong with this. When Rails is dealing with a polymorphic association, and the object being associated is using STI, it simply uses the base class as the type (in your case "commentable_type").

If you have Post and NewsArticle in separate tables, obviously the commentable_type will show up as Post and NewsArticle respectively.

Comment: How can you retrieve the comments from a NewsArticle if this is correct? I am having a similar issue where my query is returning nothing because it is searching for the base class type.